# Js fetch api post undefined as value not string

Tags: javascript, php, undefined, fetch-api, form-data

Posting data to php is working. However if the object is empty the object returns undefined as a string in php. Thus I can't use isset because value is true. How can I change it in js to make this work?

```
//php 
$keuze = isset($_POST['keuze']) ? $_POST['keuze'] : 'Vandaag';

//js
 var objdata = new Object();
    
 function init() {
  var formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append('bellijst', objdata.bellijst);
  formdata.append('callagent', objdata.callagent);
  formdata.append('keuze', objdata.keuze);
  fetch('opbouw/model/get/outboundstatistieken.php', {method: 'POST', body: formdata})
  .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    })
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
```

Solved!!

if (typeof objdata.keuze !== "undefined") formdata.append('keuze',objdata.keuze);
Credit user2182349

Comment: Don't append the property if there is no value for it (don't call `formdata.append(..)`).

Comment: `if (typeof objdata.keuze !== "undefined") formdata.append('keuze',objdata.keuze);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to check the data before set:

- !!objData.kenuze (for check the Truthy and Falsy)
- ??objData.Kenuze (for check is Null or not)
- typeof objData.kenuze !== 'undefined' (note that typeof return String as response)

and finally, need to check with some `if` statement:

```
if (!!objData.kenuze) {
    formdata.append('keuze', objdata.keuze);
}
```